# Simple way to increase volume on MP3s?

Tags: mp3

I play my MP3s over a cheap stereo.  Some MP3s are not loud enough.

Is there some a software program that makes it easy to increase the volume by, say, 10dbs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do this non-destructively (ie don't increase the volume in the file as some fidelity will be lost), you can set your EQ to +10db across the board in your media player.

Comment: Holy cow.  I didn't even realize that this setting existed.  My MP3 can only do +3db but that is enough.... thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 5):

The esiest way is to install [MP3Gain](http://mp3gain.sourceforge.net/) and use that.

> Tired of reaching for your volume knob
>   every time your mp3 player changes to
>   a new song? MP3Gain analyzes and
>   adjusts mp3 files so that they have
>   the same volume.
>
> MP3Gain does not just do peak
>   normalization, as many normalizers do.
>   Instead, it does some statistical
>   analysis to determine how loud the
>   file actually sounds to the human ear.
>   Also, the changes MP3Gain makes are
>   completely lossless. There is no
>   quality lost in the change because the
>   program adjusts the mp3 file directly,
>   without decoding and re-encoding.